# get_fieldValuesAsText usage example

Tags: javascript, formatting, jsom

I need to get items using JSOM and show them on a page in a display form. So currency field will be shown like $ 123,456.78 the date will be formatted accordingly to settings and Yes\No value will be displayed correctly.

I gues, **get_fieldValuesAsText** is what can help me best, but I can't understand how to use it and can't find any example.

Comment: Are you unsure of how to get values from list using JSOM? or just this `get_fieldValuesAsTest`?

Comment: I am unsure how to use get_fieldValuesAsTest. And I can get values using JSOM.

Comment: What code have you written till now? Can you share?

Comment: Asad, Xiaodan Mao has already added a working example, however I am still searching for a way to download all items with one server request.

Comment: For one server request, best way would be to use REST api. `http://siteurl//_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listitle')/item(itemId)/fieldvaluesastext`

Comment: Ok, I will try the REST URL. But would be nice if you know how to do same with object model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Title");
var item = list.getItemById(id);
var fieldValuesAsText = item.get_fieldValuesAsText();

clientContext.load(fieldValuesAsText);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
    var fieldValues = fieldValuesAsText.get_fieldValues(); // Text values of all fields
    var fieldValue = fieldValuesAsText.get_item('Title'); // Text value of one field
}, function (sender, args) {
    alert(args.get_message());
});
```

Update, get field values as text of all items in one executeQueryAsync call:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Title");
var items = list.getItems(new SP.CamlQuery());

clientContext.load(items, 'Include(FieldValuesAsText)');
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
    var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var item = enumerator.get_current();
        var fieldValuesAsText = item.get_fieldValuesAsText();
        var fieldValues = fieldValuesAsText.get_fieldValues();
        console.log(fieldValues);
    }
}, function (sender, args) {
    alert(args.get_message());
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This example IS working. Maybe you have an idea how to download values of ALL items with only **one clientContext.load**?

Comment: @Serhiy I've updated the code, you can check if it meets your needs.

Comment: Man, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: How could you use this to get one fieldValue as text (a lookup column), and then still pull in other columns normally?

Comment: @SabienAmbrose I don't have a good solution. But maybe you can load twice, load other columns first, then load that field as text, and then execute the query.