# JS retrieve text value from lookup

Tags: javascript, lookup-column

I am struggling with grabbing the text from a lookup column. The field contains a link with text, and in my JS code, I would like to access the field's text contents (not the link).

If I use `oListItem.get_item("columnName")`, the return value is an object (console prints [Object object]). I noticed on some forums, there was a method `get_fieldValuesAsText()`.  Link [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151485/get-fieldvaluesastext-usage-example)

This method, in theory would return the text value in the column in question. My question, is will this work, and, where can I find some examples of using this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting lookup value use this:

```
var columnFieldValue = oListItem.get_item("columnName");
var lookupValue = columnFieldValue.get_lookupValue();
var lookupId = columnFieldValue.get_lookupId();
```

Comment: When i added this line it says get_lookupValue() isn't a function?

Comment: is field "columnName" lookup? Or it has another type? If it's hyperlink type use `.get_description()` and `.get_url()`

Comment: it only worked like this: Picture += oListItem.get_item("PictureName").get_lookupValue();